# Change the order of parameters in function without breaking the existing build

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a function which helps to get data from a database. This function allows me to define the table name, required fields as a string, a where condition, order by field and optional tables to join. The function looks like this.

```
Public Function DBSELECT(Byval table As String, Byval fields As String, Byval where as String, Byval orderBy As String, Optional Byval join As String = Nothing)
```

But now I need to add a GroupBy paramter just before the join paramter, however if I were to just add that paramter it would break the code which already uses this function. Is there a way to modify this method without breaking the existing build.

Comment: Instead of using **few** paramters of type `String`, in the function which obviously will generate a sql query based on that paramters, you can use one method which take a query as parameter. without generating it

Answer (score 3):

I see two options:

1. Add the new parameter last, [with default value set to `Nothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f25e2b6b.aspx).
2. Add new [method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z71zbeh.aspx) with the parameter added, and make the existing one call that one with default value for `groupBy` provided.

Comment: the parameter join is already an optional, sorry I forgot to include it in my initial post. But now I edited the question. Is there a way to add the Byval Optional GroupBy = Nothing parameter in the middle.

And have the files currently using this function to be set to nothing automatically. I need this because I have used this function in about 100 different places & it will take a long time to edit plus it would benefit me in the future as well.

Comment: You could use tools like ReSharper to do it for you. I don't think there is anything built in VisualStudio that would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Optional parameter, but then it would have to come after the join parameter.

```
Public Function DBSELECT(Byval table As String, 
Byval fields As String, Byval where as String, 
Byval orderBy As String, Byval join As String, 
Optional Byval groupBy as String=Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the new parameter to the end as an `Optional` parameter with a default value.

Example:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Test()
        Test("Goodbye")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test(Optional ByVal opt1 As String = "Hello")
        Console.WriteLine(opt1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
Hello
Goodbye
```

In your method, you would check that the GroupBy parameter is not the default value, so you'd would know to apply it to the SQL statement.